# Replace Null value with 0 in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

Replace column with null value with 0 or any value

For the dataset test, we replace the column SalesQty `null` value with `0`

**dataset: test**

```
+---+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------+
|mon|year|mon_year|location_code|item_no|SalesQty|mmon_year_1|
+---+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 11|2012|  112012|         null|   null|    null|       null|
| 11|2012|  112012|         null|   null|    null|       null|
| 11|2012|  112012|         null|   null|    null|       null|
+---+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------+

test$SalesQty <- when(isNull(test$SalesQty), 0 )
```

**The resulting dataset result:**

```
+---+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------+
|mon|year|mon_year|location_code|item_no|SalesQty|mmon_year_1|
+---+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 11|2012|  112012|         null|   null|    0   |       null|
| 11|2012|  112012|         null|   null|    0   |       null|
| 11|2012|  112012|         null|   null|    0   |       null|
+---+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

"null" is string.

```
test$SalesQty <- ifelse(test$SalesQty == "null", 0, test$SalesQty)
```